# AJAX failed to load server with a status of 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have taken an example from the internet of working laravel with ajax. But it gives me the 500 internal server error:

> jquery.min.js:4 GET 127.0.0.1:8000/search?search=p 500 (Internal Server Error) send @ jquery.min.js:4 ajax @ jquery.min.js:4 (anonymous) @ (index):39 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3 r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

This is the code for controller called **SearchController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('search.search');
    }

    public function search(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $output="";
            $products=DB::table('products')->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
            if($products)
            {
                foreach ($products as $key => $product) {
                    $output.='<tr>'.
                                '<td>'.$product->id.'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$product->title.'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$product->description.'</td>'.
                                '<td>'.$product->price.'</td>'.
                               '</tr>';
                }
                return Response($output);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

**Code in web.php**

```
Route::get('/','SearchController@index');
Route::get('/search','SearchController@search');
```

**Code of blade file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta id="token" name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Live Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3>Products info </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-controller" id="search" name="search"></input>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Description</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
                $value=$(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type : 'get',
                    url : '{{URL::to('search')}}',
                    data:{'search':$value},
                    success:function(data){
                        $('tbody').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'csrftoken' : '{{ csrf_token() }}' } });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should display the record when the key is pressed but it gives error 500 internal server error

Screenshot with GET method
[AJAX ERROR WITH GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTZx9.png)

Screenshot with POST method
[AJAX ERROR WITH POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMEen.png)

Comment: The first thing you always do when you get an internal server error, is you go check the server’s error logs.

Comment: [quick checking] go to your Browser' s Dev tools, then `Network` tab, refresh your page, test your code, check response result there (you should find laravel error details), then provide here what you got

Comment: Check the response in the Developer tools network tab. There should be a more detailed error message.

Comment: It says jquery.min.js:4 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?search=p 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ (index):39
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Comment: Check if  `'{{ csrf_token() }}'` is actually producing the CSRF token.

Comment: Yes. It is producing the csrf_token

Comment: Could you please check the request if the body of the HTTP-method contains any parameters? Or did you searched for `p` :D

Comment: Yes, I searched for p

Comment: @JaydeepRajgor change the method to post and set the header as `{ 'x-csrf-token' : {{ csrf_token }} }`

Comment: @AdityaThakur Still not working.

Comment: @JaydeepRajgor Goto your Developer Options and then click on Network tab, then click on Reponse. let us know whats the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, There is no DB imported.
So Just write

```
use DB;
```

in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#search').on('keyup',function(){
    value=$(this).val();
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url : '{{ url('search') }}',
        method : 'POST',
        data:{'search': value},
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response.data)
        }
      });
    })
    </script>
```

your route

```
Route::post('/search','SearchController@search');
```

and in your controller, verify

```
public function search(Request $request)
{ 
 $products=DB::table('products')->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->search."%")->get();
 return response()->json(['data' => $products]);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194243/discussion-on-answer-by-aditya-thakur-ajax-failed-to-load-server-with-a-status-o).